# How to apply jquery UI effect to #name element from URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to apply a query UI effect to an element depending on the # from the URL.

i.e.: When loading www.mysite.com/page.html#name, effect() is applied to the element with the #name id while loading www.mysite.com/page.html#othername would have effect() apllied to the element with the #othername id and www.mysite.com/page03.html would simply have no effect() applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`window.location.hash` to get the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.

See [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)

In your case it will return `#name`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(  ){
        var elemName = window.location.hash;
        /* $(elemName) will retrieve the jQuery element with the corresponding 
               id and you can apply the effect to this element.*/
    });
});
```